# Error message ORA-19279: XPTY0004 received when trying to create view of XML file in PL/SQL

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, xquery

I am trying to create a view of some XML files in Oracle PL/SQL. The problem with the data content of the XML files is that a single path often has more than one data entry, as shown below:

```
<priip>
  <data>
    <properties>
      <priipMonitoringInterval>daily</priipMonitoringInterval>
      <priipMonitoringStartDate>2017-06-30T13:51:03.168000</priipMonitoringStartDate>
      <permittedKIDDownloadJurisdictions>
        <item>DE</item>
        <item>AT</item>
      </permittedKIDDownloadJurisdictions>
    </properties>
  </data>
</priip>
```

I am hence getting an error message which reads:

**ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence**

Here, clearly, the problem lies with the path:

```
priip/data/properties/permittedKIDDownloadJurisdictions/item
```

where we have two permissible jurisdictions, DE and AT. I cannot change the raw XML file, and I require all data within the files to be entered into the PL/SQL view. I have attached a sample of my code below, showing what I have already tried to do.

```
create or replace view PRIIPS_XML_VIEW as
  select *
    from PRIIPS_XML t,
      XMLTable(
        '$p/priip/data'
        passing t.SYS_NC_ROWINFO$ as "p"

        columns
          priip_monitoring_interval varchar2(20) path 'properties/priipMonitoringInterval',
          priip_monitoring_start_date varchar2(26) path 'properties/priipMonitoringStartDate',
          kid_download_jurisdiction varchar2(10) path 'properties/permittedKIDDownloadJurisdictions/item'
          );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: PLease edit your XML example to be complete and valid.

Comment: I have done so - but for the sake of brevity I have excluded much of the other contents of the file.

Comment: Well you cannot have two elements map to one row/column like that.  You somehow need to "flatten" the data.  Will the number of item elements always be two or less?  An alternative that would probably work is to use an xQuery

Comment: @OldProgrammer - yes, I will assume for now that there are a maximum of 2 jurisdictions permitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to this.  It is fragile and will not work for > 2 item elements, which in that case you will want to use xquery to do some more sophisticated stuff:

```
create or replace view PRIIPS_XML_VIEW as
  select *
    from PRIIPS_XML t,
      XMLTable(
        '$p/priip/data'
        passing t.SYS_NC_ROWINFO$ as "p"

        columns
          priip_monitoring_interval varchar2(20) path 'properties/priipMonitoringInterval',
          priip_monitoring_start_date varchar2(26) path 'properties/priipMonitoringStartDate',
          kid_download_jurisdiction varchar2(10) path       
 kid_download_jurisdiction1 varchar2(10) path 'properties/permittedKIDDownloadJurisdictions/item[1]',
          kid_download_jurisdiction2 varchar2(10) path 'properties/permittedKIDDownloadJurisdictions/item[2]' 
);
```

Comment: Thank you - this does indeed work for 2 jurisdictions.

Comment: Update (10/07/17) - it was necessary to add more than 2 jurisdictions, and I found that implementing this method also worked for this problem (despite what you warned in your answer @OldProgrammer ).

Answer (score 3):

Since Item occurs more than once it should be dealt with using a second XMLTABLE operations. This will give a normalized view of the item content.

See https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_E8GUH32UJN0EDKXRSV30ZUX4V.html

Comment: Thank you for the response. I would prefer just one data entry regardless of whether there are one or two jurisdictions; hence I'm still going to accept OldProgammer's answer.